# why the example of TextFormField does't work anymore?

Tags: flutter

The flutter [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) has an [example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html#material.TextFormField.2),

it says

> this example shows how to move the focus to the next field when the user presses the ENTER key.

but when I press the ENTER, it doesn't work, is this a bug of flutter or Am I missing something?

Comment: please post your code so that it can be compared to the one in the example

Answer (score 2):

The `LogicalKeyboardKey.enter` will stand true for mobiles and other android and Ios based keyboards. While in Your pc the functionality can be achieved by `tab` key.